# How to reduce the sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have seen the following in several places:

$$e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\lambda e^{-4}\right)^k}{k!}=e^{-\lambda +\lambda e^{-4}}$$

- Is this correct?
- If so how is this sum reduced?
- May I reduce $e^{-2\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\lambda \right)^k}{k!}(-1)^k$ in the sam way to $e^{-2\lambda-\lambda}=e^{-3\lambda}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are fine. It is just using $e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ for $x=\lambda e^{-4}$ or $x=-\lambda$.

Comment: Is there a name for $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$?

Comment: @havakok I call it the most famously known and easily remembered Taylor series.

Comment: @havakok I call it a definition.